# Nested vuedraggable - children for draggable not display

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, sortablejs, vuedraggable

I would like to achieve the effect of managing subpages (changing the order, level) on the page by dragging.

I use [vuedragabble](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) for this.

I have a problem with changing the depth levels - I think I need [**THIS**](https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/nested-with-vmodel) solution.

My code in vue 2:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <draggable v-bind="dragOptions" v-model="pagesList" class="item-container">
      <div v-for="page in pagesList" :key="page.id" class="item-group">
        <div class="item">
          {{ page.title }}
        </div>
        <draggable class="item-sub" />
      </div>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  data: () => ({
    pagesList: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Home",
        level: 1,
        order: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Offer",
        level: 1,
        order: 2,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Offer 1",
        level: 2,
        order: 3,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: "Offer 2",
        level: 2,
        order: 4,
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: "Contact",
        level: 1,
        order: 5,
      },
    ],
  }),
  computed: {
    dragOptions() {
      return {
        animation: 0,
        group: "description",
        disabled: false,
        ghostClass: "ghost",
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-bas-tpn5sd?file=/src/App.vue

What should I do to get such an effect with the ability to freely move elements and nest them?

[image]

Maybe I should change the *pageLists* structure I get from the api?

But even if I change the structure and the data looks like this:

```
pagesList: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Home",
        level: 1,
        order: 1,
        subpages: [],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Offer",
        level: 1,
        order: 2,
        subpages: [
          {
            id: 3,
            title: "Offer 1",
            level: 2,
            order: 3,
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            title: "Offer 2",
            level: 2,
            order: 4,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: "Contact",
        level: 1,
        order: 5,
        subpages: [],
      },
    ],
```

and I will also change the code:

```
<draggable :list="page.subpages" class="item-sub" />
```

it does not work - subpages not display